# ClosedVolume And SweptVolume

Tags: openmodelica, volumes

I'm currently trying to get to grips with the OpenModelica software. I'm trying to make a simple model, composed of a fixed volume, a pipe and a piston. However, when I run the simulation, I get an error and I can't get out of it. I'd also like to know how I can impose a certain amount of mass in my fixed volume. That's why I'm asking for your help. I would be grateful if you could help me.
Thanks in advance,
Have a nice day!

What I've tried:

````
  Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume sweptVolume(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir, clearance = 0.0001, nPorts = 1, pistonCrossArea = 0.001) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {18, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume volume(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir, V = 6e-4, nPorts = 1, use_portsData = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-66, 20}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-82, 80}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Air.SimpleAir, diameter = 0.8, length = 1, nParallel = 1) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-28, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.Mass mass(m = 0.1) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {54, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(volume.ports[1], pipe.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-66, 10}, {-66, 0}, {-38, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe.port_b, sweptVolume.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-18, 0}, {8, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(sweptVolume.flange, mass.flange_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{28, 0}, {44, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 0}));
  annotation(
end ClosedSwept; ```



# The error: 
# The arguments u_min and u_max provided in the function call     solveOneNonlinearEquation(f,u_min,u_max) do not bracket the root of the single non-linear equation 0=f(u):   u_min  = 200   u_max  = 6000   fa = f(u_min) = 212529   fb = f(u_max) = 7.66508e+06 fa and fb must have opposite sign which is not the case
# Process crashed Simulation process failed. Exited with code 0xffffffffc0000005.
````

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error. Which version are you using? I'm assuming latest stable on windows.

In any case, this error is a "permission denied" type of error. This might be caused by the configuration of your antivirus, or even your firewall. You might want to whitelist the folder

`C:\Program Files\OpenModelica<....>`

as well as the folder where the models run:

`C:\Users\<....>\AppData\Temp\OpenModelica`

with the `<....>` parts adapted to your machine. Additionally you might want to check in your firewall if local programs are allowed to open unprivileged ports on localhost, and if not, allow it.

Comment: Yes, that's right. 
I'm using the latest version. Thanks for your help, I was able to fix the problem.
I'd also like to ask you if you know how I can impose a certain amount of mass in my ClosedVolume. If I'm not mistaken, in the parameters I can't indicate that I can use a quantity of 124g.

Comment: No, you can't directly. But you can specify a pressure in the parameters->initialization tab.